# How do I reset a completed puzzle?

Tags: the-looker

I solved a puzzle on accident in The Looker while messing around and scribbling at random. Can I reset the puzzle to try solving it the intended way?

[image: scribbles that resemble a chaotic mess of red ketchup strewn all over the floor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't quit and saved yet you can try force closing the game. Otherwise it seems the only way to reset a completed puzzle is to erase your save file and start the game over.

Return to the tunnel where you started the game and keep walking until you reach a door. There will be a panel to your right you can solve to delete your save data.

[image: solve to delete save file]